# Ansible search for a substring in stdout output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Team,
I am trying to match a version and that fails when whole string does not match. so I just want to match first two octects. I tried several combons but no luck.

```
      - name: "Validate k8s version"
        shell: "kubectl version --short"
        register: k8s_version_live
        failed_when: k8s_version_live.stdout_lines is not search("{{ k8s_server_version }}")
        #failed_when: "'{{ k8s_server_version }}' not in k8s_version_live.stdout_lines"
        ignore_errors: yes
      - debug:
          var: k8s_version_live.stdout_lines
```

output:

````
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: k8s_version_live.stdout_lines is not search("{{
k8s_server_version }}")

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "kubectl version --short", "delta": "0:00:00.418128", "end": "2019-12-05 02:13:15.108997", "failed_when_result": true, "rc": 0, "start": "2019-12-05 02:13:14.690869", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Client Version: v1.13.3\nServer Version: v1.13.10", "stdout_lines": ["Client Version: v1.13.3", "Server Version: v1.13.10"]}
...ignoring

TASK [team-services-pre-install-checks : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 05 December 2019  02:13:15 +0000 (0:00:00.902)       0:00:01.039 *****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "k8s_version_live.stdout_lines": [
        "Client Version: v1.13.3",
        "Server Version: v1.13.10"
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

As the error says:

> conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.

In a conditional statement, you are already inside a Jinja template context. You can just refer to variables  by name:

```
- name: "Validate k8s version"
  shell: "kubectl version --short"
  register: k8s_version_live
  failed_when: k8s_version_live.stdout_lines is not search(k8s_server_version)
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Although you probably want `k8s_version_live.stdout` instead of `k8s_version_live.stdout_lines`.

I would probably write the task as:

```
- name: "Validate k8s version"
  command: "kubectl version --short"
  register: k8s_version_live
  failed_when: k8s_server_version not in k8s_version_live.stdout
  ignore_errors: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Match a version ... match first two octets*"**

A: Use [Version Comparison](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison). For example, create the variable *k8s_server_version* from the registred output

```yaml
- set_fact:
    k8s_server_version: "{{ k8s_version_live.stdout_lines.1.split(':').1[2:] }}"
```

**Compare the first two numbers of the version**

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ k8s_server_version }} match 1.13"
  when:
    - k8s_server_version is version('1.13', '>=')
    - k8s_server_version is version('1.14', '<')
```

gives

```yaml
    }
    localhost | SUCCESS => {
        "msg": "1.13.10 match 1.13"
    }
```

**Fail when the version does not match**

```yaml
- fail:
    msg: "{{ k8s_server_version }} does not match 1.12"
  when: not (k8s_server_version is version('1.12', '>=') and
             k8s_server_version is version('1.13', '<'))
```

gives

```yaml
    localhost | FAILED! => {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "1.13.10 does not match 1.12"
    }
```